# CoreData: error: exception during newFetchedPKsForSourceID: statement is still active with userInfo of (null)

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

I use core data in a background thread, when query data in a iteration using NSFetchRequest, it always get this error when executing [context executeFetchRequest: error:]:

```
2013-10-13 10:23:37.052 EExFab[157:217] CoreData: error: exception during newFetchedPKsForSourceID: statement is still active with userInfo of (null)
2013-10-13 10:23:37.056 EExFab[157:217] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'statement is still active'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2fe76f53 0x3a24f6af 0x2fbc7999 0x2fbc71e5 0x2fbe0ef7 0x2fbd67ed 0x2fbcfa6f 0x2fbf9fcf    0x2fbf91f1 0x2fbf8e21 0x2fbf8a5b 0x2fbfb715 0x2fbf7d2b 0x2fbf7b73 0x307a59a1 0x307a5645 0x30791c5d 0x2fbefa03 0x2fbee3b3 0x9b9a1 0x2fbdc5a9 0x2fbdb4cf 0x2fca4ab3 0x2fca119b 0x2fbcf085 0x2fbceb33 0x2fbce3e5 0x2fbcc7e7 0xa9d69 0xa95ad 0xa4f0b 0xa9511 0x30859e27 0x3a876c1d 0x3a876b8f 0x3a874c90)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The code is like this:

```
@implementation EExFab{
    NSString *filePath;
    NSManagedObjectModel *model;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest;
    NSArray *fetchResult;
}

-(void)prepareCoreDataVariables{
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES};
    if(!filePath)filePath=[[NSHomeDirectory()    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CDStoreOfEExFab.CDABStore"];
    if(!model)model=[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"EExFabModel" withExtension:@"momd"]];
    if(!coordinator){
        coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: model];
        if(![coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO] options:options error:&error]){
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }
    if(!context){
        context=[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
        [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
        [context setUndoManager:nil];
    }
    if(!fetRequest)fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
}

-(void)performBackgroundTask{ // invoker
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(onPerformBackgroundTask) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

-(void)onPerformBackgroundTask{
    [self prepareCoreDataVariables];
    // .... perform creation of Parsing some data into Core Data Storage using the variables
    // .... NO error occurs during this period. ....
    [self prepareCoreDataVariables];
    for (id obj in someFetchedArray){
        fetchRequest=[[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EExFabOBJ" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(timeOfCreation == %@)",obj.timeOfCreation]];
        NSError *err=nil;
        // ***************************CRASH*********************************************
        fetchResult=[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&err]; // <<<<<CRASH
        // ***************************CRASH*********************************************
        // .... other things ...
    }
}
```

The app crashed at the first time of execution of the above code, there is no other thread or block using or used the local Core Data variables. Actually, these variables are initialized by the background thread itself.

Please pay attention on the block just above the crashed iteration, the Core Data Storage is initialized and parsed to be created in that block, they are in the same thread.

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: Does the crash still happen if you move everything to the main thread?

Comment: @ArkadiuszHolko Yes, it still crash in the main thread.

Comment: Can you see what happens when you remove the second `[self prepareCoreDataVariables];`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszHolko, Nothing else happen, just crash. Actually, this code runs OK before I added some code about the default notification center, but now I have already rolled back, it still crashes at that line.

Comment: Seems like a very strange way to do things... for starters, you need to set up an autorelease pool for your background thread. However, there are probably better ways to do things in the background such as using an NSOperation subclass. Also, you're performing several fetches in a loop. I don't see why you would need to do that. You should be able to specify the data you need using just the predicate. Either way, a better approach is to fetch more data than you need and then filter it down using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`

Comment: i'm facing the same issues, but only when testing on iPad Air ios 8.3, if i change the ios version to 8.1 it works without failure. If i use the same ios version ( 8.3) at iPad 2 or iPad Retina the issue doesn't happen.